# Facebook like url not working anymore, since Facebook removed the old app page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

Since a few weeks now, the like button on [our Facebook app](http://apps.facebook.com/lindoplay) is not working anymore. And I think I know what the problem is:

First we had the standard Facebook app page and i gave this app the following nice url: facebook.com/LindoPlay.Keno
This is the url we used for our like button on the Facebook app.

```
    <fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/LindoPlay.Keno" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Now Facebook deleted all old Facebook app pages which means the URL facebook.com/LindoPlay.Keno just redirects to our Facebook app now. Since then the like button is not working anymore with this URL.

If I use the app URL in the like button (apps.facebook.com/lindoplay) it DOES work. But only with 330 likes. The other URL (www.facebook.com/LindoPlay.Keno) had 1600+ likes.

So in short the question is: Is there a way to get the http://www.facebook.com/LindoPlay.Keno URL to work again in the like button and get our 1600 likes back?

Thanks,
Tristan

Comment: Please ask [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012) about this. This is a programmers' Q&A site. We are not Facebook and we can't give you back your likes.

Comment: likes on urls don't mean shit in value to anything other than to business and marketing. Actually, it is a good thing if you can start over. People will be able to click again, and their friends will be notified again

Comment: @Topener That's a nice thought, will consider that